# Convert a LCD HD monitor to a tv?

Tags: tv, high-definition

I have a 22" 1080p HD monitor that I used to use to stream netflix from my computer. Now I want to:

Use my computer (or a Roku) to stream Hulu & Netflix. 
Then also use it to connect to a over the air box to get over the air HD tv.

Problems: I have no speakers on the monitor and only 1 HD input, 1 DVI and 1 VGA. I have a pair of external desktop speakers that I would like to use.

Any suggestions? I'm a poor college student so solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time for a dish of [Rasberry Pi!](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) the $25 computer.

there is a port of XBMC (Popular media playing linux distro) that is available for the ARM architecture that the PI uses.

[image]

Comment: How can I get over the air TV on this?

Comment: Use a XBMC supported USB TV Tuner, or have a tuner on your network: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:Watch_TV_in_XBMC

Comment: Same goes for adding storage, either use a shared folder on the network or a USB hard drive.